# Form Validation all letters

Tags: javascript, html

Hi Please find the below form validation code. I've used html5 input attributes for most of the validation except where i need all letter for the first name and last name. The below cose is what i wrote for first name...but looks like it's not entering the if condition. Can anyone please help
and lemme know where I went wrong.....Thanks Guys!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function formvalid(){

var uname=document.form1.usrname.value;
var letters=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if (uname.value.match(letters)){
alert("Your details have been saved.Please submit the course fee at the cash counter before 13/12/2014 and collect your id card.The training will start on 23/12/2014 from 10.30am to 4.40 pm");
return true;
}else{
alert("Please Enter a valid Username");
uname.focus();
return false;
}

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<h1> Register Online</h1>
<Table>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="usrname" required></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> Last Name</td>
<td><input type="text" id="usrname1"  required></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> Email ID</td>
<td><input type="email" id="mail" pattern="[^@]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}" required></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> Roll Number</td>
<td><input type="number" min="1" id="roll" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Training Program</td>
<td><select id="sel">
<option value="movie">Select Training</option>
<option value="andro">Android</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
<option value="C">Robotics</option>
    <option value="hack">Ethical Hacking</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number</td>
<td><input type="number" min="1" id="number" required></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<Button type="submit" onclick="return formvalid()">Submit</BUTTON></td>
<td><BUTTON type="reset">Reset</BUTTON>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `uname.value.match` to just `uname.match` because `uname` is already a value.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line with the `if`, and see what values the variables have. Try evaluating `uname.value`, for instance. Do you know how to "debug"? It's actually a **MUCH** more efficient way of finding problems in your code than posting to SO each time.

Comment: Thank you @abhitalks....taking off the value worked :)